# Why do the size of gaps/energy between different energy levels of mercury Hg vary as it goes further away from the mercury atom?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

In hydrogen, the gap is getting increasing smaller, this is understandable: there will not be as much energy released as it goes down, and as attraction gets weaker.

But in mercury the ordering is kinda counterintuitive. 
[image]

As can be seen in the part of the diagram on the right, e-d is bigger a leap than d-c. But the latter pair is further away from the nucleus and less attracted to it.

Comment: Could you show (with a diagram) what it is you are asking, exactly? "As it goes further away from mercury" may make sense to you - but to the rest of us it sounds like a space mission.

Comment: @Floris, sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in your mercury diagram is the phrase "a few energy levels". In the hydrogen diagram, the lines were labeled with "n-1, n=2" etc; the mercury lines were labeled only with letters.

You could write down the energy level of all possible states of all electrons in all orbits - you would find that there are many of them.

However, just because an energy level exists does not mean that there is a valid transition between any two levels. In quantum mechanics, we recognize "forbidden transitions" where some quantity that should be conserved, isn't. You can read about selection rules in the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule).

The diagram you show has only "strong" mercury lines in it - energies corresponding to transitions that can occur with reasonable probability. For hydrogen, the lines that can be formed are given in this diagram which is taken from [this lab assignment on spectral lines](http://www2.ohlone.edu/people/jklent/labs/101a_labs/lightspectrum.pdf):

[image]

I think your mercury diagram is simply a "sketch" rather than a full description of all possible energy levels. For example, if you look at [the NIST website on spectral data](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/mercurytable5.htm) you see the following table:

[image]

But if you look at the actual lines that can be calculated, you end up with something more complex, like http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/img610.png for example:

[image]

In short - your second table is simplified, showing only a few of the energy levels that are most relevant to spectroscopy - not all possible levels of all possible electrons.

Answer (score 0):

The energy levels can be found in the solutions of the time-independent Schrodinger equation for a system with a harmonic oscillator. For atoms with more than one electron, the situation becomes complicated: the Hamiltonian operator depends on a potential that has to take into account the relative position of not only the electron to the nucleus, but also to the other electrons in orbit. The partial differential equation you get at that point gives you energy levels that are not evenly distributed because, well... you plug it into your computer and ask it to approximate solutions to this gnarly PDE and see that it's complicated, or you run a few experiments, well, and anyway it's complicated.

Edit: it's a 1/r potential, not an r^2 harmonic oscillator potential, so I was wrong about the spacing of the energy levels, but the point remains about the electron-electron potential contributions.